# AWS Environment Variables in CodePipeline for Django Database Connection

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I have been looking at CodePipeline with a basic Django Project and wanted to setup some database connections.   I have been using a AWS CodeStar to create a basic project and then extending it into a 'beta' section and a 'prod' section with a manual sign off in between.   I wanted the Django Project to connect to dbBeta if it was in the beta environment and dbProd if it was in the production environment.

When I look at the build stage of the project, it is possible to create an environment variable, eg ENV    'BETA' (although I used PRERELEASE in this image)

[image: Image from CodeBuild]

However, when I ssh into the EC2 instances it appears that these environment variables only exist in the build section (I believe this is done in docker), but not in the EC2 instances that are created (FYI:   I am creating Elastic Beanstalk, not individual EC2 instances).

It did occur to me that I could try to muck around with the CloudFormation template file so that it wrote 'PROD' or 'BETA' into an environment variable ( and the .bash_profile) when it was created.

What I was wondering is if this is correct or if I am completely missing something.   What is the easiest/best way to get a Django Project to connect to a different database, depending on its stage in CodePipeline ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did find these articles that talked about tagging strategies:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-practice-for-staging-dev-environments-on-AWS

https://d0.awsstatic.com/aws-answers/AWS_Tagging_Strategies.pdf

https://www.slsmk.com/using-python-and-boto3-to-get-instance-tag-information/

At present, I am mucking around on AWS by myself, so setting up separate accounts for dev/prod etc seems like a bit of an over-kill.   It did occur to me that I could change the database connection based upon a tag, such as Environment : Prod, but would love to know if there are better ways to do this ?